# What is an "Enchousen situation"?

Tags: gintama

I came across this phrase in this [r/Gintama thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Gintama/comments/6l08k3/porori_arc_pool_episode_sorry_to_disappoint/) about the Porori Arc mentioned in a "new season" announcement. The original poster said:

> Now this could STILL turn out to be an Enchousen situation, which I am hoping, but for now all we know is that we'll be getting a pool episode rerun.

A commenter also said:

> im sure its an enchousen situation
>   at least i hope!

What is an Enchousen situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At that time, it was still not clear exactly how many new episodes will be in the Porori Arc and I believe they are just referring to the possibility of Porori Arc being a full cour of Gintama like the Enchousen instead of just a couple of extras like Aizome Kaori.